# Time series with multiple dependent variables

Tags: r

I have got a dataframe with following columns
  product,date,sales

e.g
 data

```
        product date      sales
         A      1/1/2011  100 
         A      2/1/2011  102
         ..     .. 
         B      1/1/2011   50 
         B      2/1/2011   50
```

I have done forecasting using one variable but dont know how to do when there are multiple dependent variables
I want to plot the time series plot of all products including their forecasted value
using the trellis plot

Comment: Are you looking for something like this: `require(lattice); xyplot(sales ~ date | grp, data=temp, panel=function(x, y, ...) {panel.xyplot(x, y, ..., type="l")})`?